# Repeat last column in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

#### Problem

I am trying to repeat the last column in a Numpy array. Is there a more "elegant" way than resizing the array, copying the values and repeating the last row x times?

#### What I want to achieve

```
Input Array:                        Output Array:
[[1,2,3],                           [[1,2,3,3,3],
 [0,0,0],    -> repeat(2-times) ->   [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,2,1]]                            [0,2,1,1,1]]
```

#### How I solved the problem

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[0,2,1]])
# to repeat last row two times two times
new_size = x.shape[1] + 2
new_x = np.zeros((3,new_size))
new_x[:,:3] = x

for i in range(x.shape[1],new_size):
    new_x[:,i] = x[:,-1]
```

#### Other way

Is there a way to solve this problem with the numpy repeat function?
Or something shorter or more efficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
a = np.hstack((arr, np.tile(arr[:, [-1]], 2)))
print (a)
[[1 2 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Broadcasting is often efficient.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 1000))

np.hstack((A, np.broadcast_to(A[:, -1][:, None], (A.shape[1], n))))
```

Some benchmarking if performance is an issue:

```
n = 1000
%timeit np.hstack((A, np.broadcast_to(A[:, -1][:, None], (A.shape[1], n))))  # 3.06 ms
%timeit np.hstack((A, np.tile(A[:, [-1]], n)))                               # 9.33 ms
%timeit np.repeat(A, [1]*(A.shape[1]-1) +[n], axis=1)                        # 12.9 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.repeat()`:

```
np.repeat(a, [1]*(a.shape[1]-1) +[3], axis=1)
```